# Python :only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python-3.x

I am a newbie Electrical engineering background and working on computer algorithms for research, at some stage i am stuck don't know how to overcome

[image]

the output is
[image]

i replaced a[i] with a[:] but
[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the code into the question, rather than providing screenshots. This makes it easy for everyone else to try and run the code themselves.

Comment: import numpy as np
a=np.linspace(2,0)
print(a)
b=1
c=2
d=b+c
e=c-b
for i in a:
    if a<1:
        print(d)
    elif a>=1:
        print(e)
    else:
        print(a)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to index the array by the element value. Look closely at your statement:

```
for i in a:
```

Here, in each iteration of the loop, `i` is simply each element of the array `a`, not the index. This is because `a` is an `iterable`, that is, "an object capable of returning its members one at a time."  See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) for the definition and explanation.

Hence, when you ask for `a[i]`, guess what happens? The first element is `2.0`, which is a float.  You're trying to perform `a[2.0]`, which is illegal in all known programming languages.  As the error message tells you, floats are not among the accepted types for an index.

You should simply do `if i < 1` etc., to make your conditions work as expected.

Comment: import numpy as np
a=np.linspace(2,0)
print(a)
b=1
c=2
d=b+c
e=c-b
for i in a:
    if a<1:
        print(d)
    elif a>=1:
        print(e)
    else:
        print(a)

Comment: Sorry, that condition should be `if i < 1`.  See updated answer.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that your final `else` branch will never execute.  Any given number is either < 1 or  >= 1.  There is no other possibility.

Comment: I'd appreciate it greatly if you'd accept my answer.